# Best way to program a ripple fade in effect using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, delay, fadein

I'm pretty new to jQuery and I am practicing a fade in that starts with one image and then continues to the next image and so on. I have written a piece of code (below) but was wondering if there was an easier or more elegant way to write it? I tried the each() function but didn't seem to work:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.8.2 .min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    //alert($("div img").length);
    $("div img").css("display","none");
    var delayAmt=0;
    for(var x=0;x<$("div img").length;x++){
        $("div img:eq("+x+")").delay(delayAmt).fadeIn(1000);
        delayAmt+=250;
    }
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<h1>Ripple fade in.</h1>
<div>
<img src="images/hot.jpg" id="target0">
<img src="images/hot.jpg" id="target1">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are countless JQuery plugins that do slideshows and stuff. I'd recommend the flexslider. http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you were doing. Nevermind.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<body>
<h1>Ripple fade in.</h1>
<div id="images">
<img src="images/hot.jpg" id="target0">
<img src="images/hot.jpg" id="target1">
</div>
</body>
</html>​​​
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var delay=0;
   $('#images').children('img').each(function () {
      $(this).css("display","none");
      $(this).delay(delay).fadeIn(1800);
      delay += 1000;
   }); 
});
```

jsFiddle link here: http://jsfiddle.net/salih0vicX/6GZt6/